# Is f differentiable at 0 for these two functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I fail to see how are these two functions different in terms of differentiability.

For (a) I would say that f is differentiable at 0 as left and right limits are the same, but what about (b)?

How could I prove this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \tag 1$$

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Applying $(1)$ to the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^n\sin(1/x)&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$we have $$\begin{align}f'(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^n\sin(1/h)}{h}\\\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{n-1}\sin(1/h)\end{align}$$For $n=1$, the limit does not exist while for $n=2$ the limit is $0$.  And we are done!

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.